# Check for Valid Email with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to use jQuery to see if a user has entered a valid email address into my text box. 
Basically, I want the submit button to remain disabled by default, but on each keyup I want to see if the email address is valid, then I want to enable the button. If the user enters a valid email but then deletes parts so that it becomes invalid again (i.e. the @ symbol) I want the submit button to become disabled again.

I have a partially working script here. My check or the @ symbol works well, but I am having a hard time checking for .com, .co, .net, .org, .edu etc... For some reason, the button keeps enabling even though I have not entered a valid "ending" to the email.

For example "emailco@" is recognized as a valid email. Here is my script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#email').bind('keyup', function(e) {

        var email = document.getElementById("email");

        if (email.value.search("@") != -1) {

            if (
            (email.value.search(".com") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".co") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".org") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".net") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".gov") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".biz") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".me") != -1)||
            (email.value.search(".edu") != -1)) {

            document.getElementById("email_go").disabled = false; 
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById("email_go").disabled = true; 
        }
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById("email_go").disabled = true; 
        }
    }); 
});
</script>
```

Comment: google regex email validation

Comment: Just an unrelated hint: `document.getElementById("email_go")` can become `$('#email_go')` and `document.getElementById("email")` can become `$(this)`

Comment: @andy `document.getElementById("email_go")` != `$('#email_go')`

Comment: Note: Proper email format verification is *incredibly* complex. If you do something simplistic, you *will* prevent people using valid addresses.

Comment: Try `/.*@.*(com|co|org|net|gov|biz|me.edu)$/.test(email.value)` for what you have done

Comment: Note that if you use `<input type='email'>` it will validate for you on supported browsers (ie most of them). Also whatever validation you do, be sure to also validate on the server -- javascript code can be bypassed by the user if they want to.

Comment: Thank you all for the help! testing these solutions out now! :)

Comment: @andy `[0]` sure is, but that wasn't mentioned ;)

Comment: @anOG - An oversight ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use regex:

```
if (email.value.search("@") != -1) {

    if (/(.+)@(.+)\.(com|edu|org|etc)$/.test(email.value))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var email = $('#email').val();
    var pattern = ".+\\@@.+\\..+";
        var valid = email.match(pattern);
        if (valid == null) {
           alert("Not Valid");
           return;
        }
    else{
           alert("Valid");
           return;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Of course, this is just a basic example and I'm sure that email addresses nowadays can end in more than just what's specified in the array below. But, still... you get the idea...

```
//  Split the email to see if there's an "@" character
    var split = email.split('@');
    var split_count = split.length;

//  If there is, then split the second string by a "."
    if (split_count == 2) {
        var domain = split[1].split('.');
        var domain_count = domain.length;

        if (domain_count == 2) {
//          Store all of the accepted values for email endings
            var endings = ['org', 'com', 'net', 'edu', 'info', 'biz', 'me'];
            var result = $.inArray(domain[1], endings);

//          If the final 3 chars of the string are in the array, then proceed
            if (result > 0) {

            }
      }
  }
```

Comment: You seriously want to store all available TLDs manually? What about `.pl`, `.gda.pl`, `.fr`, `.nz`, `.xxx`, `.is`, `.co.uk`? It's no use writing them out by hand, mate.

Comment: True. Nowadays, this is kinda obsolete. I'm sure you could find a list of all acceptable TLD's and store them in an array though

Comment: There is a list: http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1 & http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt. But even that isn't 100% accurate and there are far too many results to check against. A regex, IMHO, is the best option (it offers speed, and in case a new TLD, or a 2nd/3rd level domain pops up, you will support it).

Comment: Fair enough. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1):

I use this Regex Code to test email format using jQuery:

```
var email = $('.email').val();
    if(email.match(/^\w+@[a-zA-Z_]+?\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}$/))
    {
        alert('OK');
    }
```